# Rails/ActiveRecord: How can I find rows in a table that point to rows in another that match all the specified column values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models named `Issue` and `Label`. Each `issue` can have many `labels`. Each `label` can have many `issues`.

I am trying to build a query that will return an issue that contains all of the supplied labels.

For instance, if I supply `['bug', 'fix', 'enhancement']` I want issues that have all three of those three labels at least.

Currently, I have:

```
labels = ['bug', 'fix', 'enhancement']
Issue.joins(:labels).where(labels: { name: labels }).distinct
```

But this is insufficient as it returns issues that have at least one of the label names. I see this is because is because an 'IN' operator is generated:

```
WHERE "labels"."name" IN ('bug', 'fix', 'enhancement')
```

And from here on, I'm lost. The `labels` array can be any length. Can I get the result I want in a single query?

How can I find rows in a table that point to rows in another that match all the specified column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check it, but maybe this approach could work

```
Issue.select('issues.id, count(labels.id) as cnt').includes(:labels).where(labels: { name: labels }).group('issues.id').having("cnt = #{labels.size}");
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what that does and would appreciate an explanation. However, it's causing some existing tests to fail with a syntax error and when I test it in the console it only returns an empty active record relation.

Comment: i updated the answer, what error did you get? i use mysql

Comment: Thanks. It works. Now that I've had time to look at it properly, I see that the tests were breaking on a method that merges on query with the query in question. I'm not yet sure why my originally query works but this one doesn't. They both return similar rows. `Issue.joins(:language).where(languages: { name: language }).merge(Issue.joins(:labels).where(labels: { name: labels }).distinct)`